# How to remove a linebreak in a text file VBScript

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript

I have numerous CSV files and they don't import correctly to excel, im just asking is there a way to remove the line breaks at the end of the strLine using VBScript?

Comment: I doubt that removing line endings from a file will improve the import into Excel. Publishing a sample of your input file and more details about the 'not-correct' result may help you to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can remove line breaks from CSVs. `ReadLine` will automatically remove line breaks from the end of the line:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = "C:\path\to\your.csv"

f1 = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
f2 = fso.OpenTextFile(filename & ".tmp", 2, True)
Do Until f1.AtEndOfStream
  f2.Write f1.ReadLine
Loop
f1.Close
f2.Close
```

Or you could read the whole file and replace the line breaks:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = "C:\path\to\your.csv"

text = fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll
fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2).Write Replace(text, vbNewLine, ",")
```

However, that might be addressing a symptom rather than the cause. I second Ekkehard.Horner's comment: for a better answer you should definitely provide more details about your input file and the way the import fails.